# Rails Error with Mysql2 field name doesnt have a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Mysql2::Error: Field 'USER_NAME' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `dashboard_user` VALUES ()
```

I am getting this error when i am trying to open my page `http//127.0.0.1:3000/my/user_creation`

can someone help with this?

below is the model

```
class CreateDashboardUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table "dashboard_user", primary_key: "USER_ID", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "USER_NAME",            limit: 50,  null: false
    t.string   "NORMALIZED_USER_NAME", limit: 50
    t.string   "PASSWORD",             limit: 50
    t.string   "LAST_NAME",            limit: 50
    t.string   "FIRST_NAME",           limit: 50
    t.string   "MIDDLE_NAME",          limit: 50
    t.string   "PHONE",                limit: 15
    t.string   "EMAIL_ID",             limit: 100
    t.integer  "SEQ_QUES_ID"
    t.string   "SEQ_QUES_ANSWER",      limit: 100
    t.string   "EXPIRE_PASSWORD_IND",  limit: 1
    t.date     "EXPIRE_PASSWORD_DATE"
    t.string   "DEACTIVATED_IND",      limit: 1
    t.date     "DEACTIVATED_DATE"
    t.integer  "ROLE_ID"
    t.string   "CREATED_BY",           limit: 50
    t.datetime "CREATED_DATE"
    t.string   "UPDATED_BY",           limit: 50
    t.datetime "UPDATED_DATE"
    end
  end
end
```

controller code is below

```
 class AdminController < ApplicationController
      def user_creation
         DashboardUser.create(:USER_NAME => params[:username])
         DashboardUser.create(:PASSWORD => params[:password])
         DashboardUser.create(:LAST_NAME => params[:lastname])
         DashboardUser.create(:FIRST_NAME => params[:firstname])
         DashboardUser.create(:MIDDLE_NAME => params[:middlename])
         DashboardUser.create(:PHONE => params[:phone])
        redirect_to :action => 'user_creation'
      end
      private
      def dashboard_params
      params.require(:dashboard_user).permit(:id, :user_name, :password, :last_name, :first_name, :middle_name , :phone)
      end

end
```

Mysql2::Error: Field 'USER_NAME' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `dashboard_user` VALUES () this is what i get when i run it in the browser

dashboard_user

```
class DashboardUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "dashboard_user"
end
```

Comment: Post the code for user_creation action (or whichever action this url routes to). Also post the result of `desc dashboard_user` from mysql console.

Comment: added the user_Creation and dashboard_user

Comment: didn't read up on CRUD then?

Comment: @Richlewis i didnt know what to read on :\

Comment: seriously? are you joking?

Comment: have you not even read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you create an ActiveRecord::Base object. Please refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#create for information.

See if this works.

```
DashboardUser.create(
  :USER_NAME => params[:username],
  :PASSWORD => params[:password],
  :LAST_NAME => params[:lastname],
  :FIRST_NAME => params[:firstname],
  :MIDDLE_NAME => params[:middlename],
  :PHONE => params[:phone]
)
```

(P.S It will be better to read the basics before you do anything else on this!)

Comment: ok i got this and then when i click the add user i get some routing errorNo route matches [POST] "/admin/user_creation"

Rails.root: /home/vadmin/Ruby/Dashboard/Dashboard @Richlewis

Comment: also i resolved the post error but the value is not storing in the database

Comment: There's no point in resolving single errors unless you know what to do next. I suggest taking a step back and read the tutorials properly.